# Why doesn't it work properly that progressDialog.dismiss() called in onPostExecute() with the following code?

Tags: android

It depends on where I call progressDialog.show().

If I called it like the following code, the dialog will be closed.

```
/** AsyncTask **/

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    mProgressDialog.setMax(MAX_VALUE);
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
    mProgressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    mProgressDialog.dismiss(); // it works!!
    super.onPostExecute(o);
}
```

But If I use the following code, it doesn't work.
I mean the dialog isn't closed.

```
/** A.java **/

private DownloadListener mDownloadListener = new DownloadListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        ...

        } else {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mDecompressor.initialize(mContext, mDecompressListener);
                }
            }, 0);
        }
    }
};

/** B.java **/

public void initialize(final Context context,
                       final DecompressListener listener) {
    if(initialized(context)) return;

    showProgressBar(context);

    ...

    mUnzipTask = new UnzipTask(context, mProgressDialog, listener, dirPath, filePath);
    mUnzipTask.execute();
}

private void showProgressBar(final Context context) {
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    ...
    mProgressDialog.show();
}

/** AsyncTask **/

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    mProgressDialog.dismiss(); // it doesn't work (Dialog isn't closed)
    super.onPostExecute(o);
}
```

I'm confused 'cause both cases also open the dialog on UI Thread.
But the first one works and the second one doesn't work.

Anyone who knows what it's different for?

Comment: `mProgressDialog` seems to be initialized only inside `onPreExecute()` here in your code .. So are you getting an NPE ?

Comment: Can you paste the whole code? Where is mProgressDialog.show(); called from?

Comment: @ADM there is no NPE. The dialog isn't just closed.

Comment: @user3783123 K, then I'll edit it what you are wondering about.

Comment: Can you explain how the second part is related to each other? Are they somehow calling each other?

Comment: @jle I updated code more concretely. The call flow is A -> B -> AsyncTask from callback.

Comment: I would use Log.d to check if your dialog is not being shown twice and if your onPostExcecute is called at all.

Comment: @user3783123 But all flow is the same for two cases. The only different thing is where progressDialog.show() called, I think.

Comment: Interesting case!! Check in Logcat if you are getting this error message " Tried to dismissDialog() but the Dialog's window was already destroyed!");"

Comment: If the initialize() function is being called twice you would only dismiss the second dialog and the first one still being shown.